# ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in JSON at position 6 in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have integrated angular full calendar in angular 2 application but when I am trying to getting data from json file holding events list getting an error in console.log.
ERROR:

```
ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in JSON at position 6
    at Object.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.Body.json (http.es5.js:796)
    at MapSubscriber.project (events.service.ts:15)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:77)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.es5.js:1205)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.706.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:398)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:4116)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.706.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:397)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.706.Zone.runTask (zone.js:165)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:460)
```

full-calendar.component.ts

```
 export class FullCalendarComponent implements OnInit {

  getEvent:object;

  constructor(private eventsService:EventsService){}

  ngOnInit(){

      this.eventsService.getEvents().subscribe(getEvent => this.getEvent = getEvent);
  }
}
```

events.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class EventsService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  getEvents()
  {

    return this.http.get('src/assets/data/events.json').map(response => response.json().data);

  }
}
```

events.json

```
{
    "date": [
          {
            "title": "All Day Event",
            "start": "2017-04-01"
          }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your method in the service you are using `data` property and your response returns `date`

```
  getEvents()
  {

    return this.http
                   .get('src/assets/data/events.json')
                   .map(response => response.json().date);////////////////////////////

  }
```